# Parse json elements using python3

Tags: python, json

I want to parse this data from thingspeak so that in python I can do a mathematical operation on field 1 against another similar variable and also parse the created_at into a format so that I can do a date/time difference from that record to the present date time, etc.

Search lots of google but haven't found what works since I am novice I am not sure what to look for exactly.

```
 `URL='https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/CHANNELID/fields/1.json? 
 api_key='
 KEY='READ KEY'
 HEADER='&results=1'
 TIMEZONE='&timezone=America%2FChicago'
 NEW_URL=URL+KEY+HEADER+TIMEZONE
 #print(NEW_URL)

 get_data=requests.get(NEW_URL).json()
 #print(get_data)
 channel_id=get_data['channel']['id']

 field_1=get_data['feeds']
 print(field_1)`
```

This results in:

> [{'entry_id': 3131, 'created_at': '2019-03-29T10:48:04-05:00', 'field1': '10.3'}]

So I want to parse the float value of `field1` which at present is `10.3`

and

parse `created_at` into a variable that can be used to do a date/time difference

Comment: So you want `float(field_1[0]['field1'])`?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `float()` parsing function, which allow you to parse a string into floating point number:

```
float_numb = float(field_1[0]["field1"])
```

For datetime parsing, you can use `dateutil`'s `parser.parser()` function

```
from dateutil import parser
created_at = parser.parse(field_1[0]["created_at"])
```

I tried this approach it seems to work well

```
import requests
from dateutil import parser

URL='https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/CHANNELID/fields/1.json?api_key='
KEY='READ KEY'
HEADER='&results=1'
TIMEZONE='&timezone=America%2FChicago'
NEW_URL=URL+KEY+HEADER+TIMEZONE
#print(NEW_URL)

get_data=requests.get(NEW_URL).json()
#print(get_data)
channel_id=get_data['channel']['id']

field_1=get_data['feeds']
print(field_1)
float_numb = float(field_1[0]["field1"])
created_at = parser.parse(field_1[0]["created_at"])
```